# Azure DataBrick PYTHONPATH pointing at imported wheel?

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

I successfully created a python wheel of my python project following simple steps from here: https://python101.pythonlibrary.org/chapter39_wheels.html

Then from my DataBrick Notebook, installed my project dependencies (I uploaded separately my project's requirements.txt to my blob storage):

```
%pip install -r /dbfs/mnt/testdb-blob-container1/requirements.txt
```

I then uploaded python wheel of my project via Azure DataBrick interface: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/libraries/workspace-libraries

From my DataBrick Notebook, i successfully reference:

```
import myproject
import myproject.src
from myproject.src.core import constants as constants   <-- This is fine.
```

But this blew up because my datetimeutil needs "constants". From local, we have PYTHONPATH. In DataBrick, we dont have this, so below attempt to import datetimeutil below up:

```
  from myproject.src.helpers import datetimeutil as datetimeutil
```

How do we set PYTHONPATH in DataBrick environment?

One thing i tried is... my wheel file is here:

```
dbfs:/FileStore/jars/23011937_5e16_4be0_b82a_88e83aaecadf/myproject-1.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

From my notebook:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("dbfs:/FileStore/jars/23011937_5e16_4be0_b82a_88e83aaecadf/")
```

This did **not** work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to you cluster > Libraries and click on Install New button.

With Library Source = Upload and Library Type = Python Whl drag and drop the whl file. This will install the python custom library on the Databricks cluster.

Comment: i did. See what i done above. However this custom python libraries require PYTHONPATH to work properly. "datetimeutil.py" has an import statement: from core import constants as constants    --- if PYTHONPATH not set, it wont import other python files within this custom project properly.

Comment: I think that you need to package your library correctly, with correct `__init__.py`, etc.

Comment: i did. Every folder has __init__.py, thats why i am able to reference some simple python scripts in my project. But some others python scripts has dependencies that references other python files in project (not those in requirements.txt). That's where things break down.

Comment: Have you tried setting the environment variable at the cluster level? It is on the Advanced Options > Spark tab.